# Found java.util.concurrent.Future Required scala.concurrent.Future

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-http, reactive-kafka

Related: [scala.concurrent.Future wrapper for java.util.concurrent.Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215421/scala-concurrent-future-wrapper-for-java-util-concurrent-future)

This came from my other question:

[How to integrate akka streams kafka (reactive-kafka) into akka http application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099303/how-to-integrate-akka-streams-kafka-reactive-kafka-into-akka-http-application)

I have a AKKA HTTP application, and I'd like to send a message/ProducerRecord to Kafka in the onComplete function in my route, like the following:

```
val producer : KafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer(producerSettings)

val routes : Route = 
  post {
    entity(as[User]) { user =>
      val createUser = userService.create(user)
      onSuccess(createUser) {
        case Invalid(y: NonEmptyList[Err]) =>  
          complete(BadRequest -> "invalid user")
        case Valid(u: User) => { 
          val producerRecord = 
            new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], String]("topic1","some message")

          onComplete(producer.send(producerRecord)) { _ =>
            complete(ToResponseMarshallable((StatusCodes.Created, u)))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However, the **onComplete(producer send producerRecord)** is generating the following type mismatch error:

[error]  found   : Future[org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata] (in java.util.concurrent) 
[error]  required: Future[org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata] (in scala.concurrent) 
[error]             onCompleteRecordMetadata { _ =>

Is there any way around this, maybe by using the Producer as as sink (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/producer.html#producer-as-a-sink) instead of the java **producer.send** function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage [Cake's Scala based Kafka client](https://github.com/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client/), which will do the work of running Java futures and giving you Scala futures back. Once you make sure you create a `cakesolutions.kafka.KafkaProducer` instead of a `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer`, the rest of your code should practically stay the same.

Alternatively, you can sort this out leveraging [Reactive Kafka](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka) whilst keeping using the high level Akka HTTP DSL. You can do it by running your producer record to a Kafka Sink, this way:

```
val producerSink = Producer.plainSink(producerSettings)

...
        // inside the route
        val producerRecord =
          new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], String]("topic1", "some message")

        onComplete(Source.single(producerRecord).runWith(producerSink)) { _ =>
          complete(ToResponseMarshallable((StatusCodes.Created, u)))
        }
```

Comment: Don't ever do that in production code. Using `Source.single` to send each and every Kafka message is 10x times inefficient, compared to plain producer.send.It materialises the whole stream each time, including actor and everything.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question, the [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) library provides converters between java8 and Scala Futures.

Specifically, you can use [`FutureConverters.toScala(producer.send(producerRecord))`](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/compat/java8/FutureConverters.scala#L78) to convert the `java.util.concurrent.Future` to `scala.concurrent.Future`

However, using a client library that has a Scala-friendly API itself (as suggested by Stefano above) will probably get you the best result.